# Get decimal number from float in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I need to convert float representation of time (02.35) to minutes.

So I get 02 by floor function (floor(02.35) = 2.) and multiply that by 60.

How can I get the the decimal number (35) from the float number (02.35)?

Thanks!

Comment: Floating point numbers are subject to precision problems. Rational numbers seem to be a better fit for this, or, as @repeat already suggested, maybe use two integer components to represent hours and minutes?

Comment: @mat. Actually, I was in favor of using floats for datetime information! But the representation should better avoid gaps/ambiguities. The limited precision of floats is not a problem in this case, IMO.

Comment: I cannot recommend floats in this case: Date and times are often given in decimals, and many decimal numbers like `0.1` cannot be represented with finite floats. See for example: `?- format("~20f", [0.1]).`, yielding: `0.10000000000000000555`. Rationals or tuples of integers are a much better choice for this in my view.

Answer (score 0):

So I tried different approaches and this works.

```
time_to_minutes(TimeAsDouble, TimeInMinutes):-
    HH is floor(TimeAsDouble),
    MM is integer(100*(TimeAsDouble-HH)),
    TimeInMinutes is ((HH*60) + MM).
```

**EDIT**: Fixed the code

Comment: My bad, fixed it. Thanks

Comment: Ok. The representation you use is somewhat weird; not necessarily wrong, but the query `?- time_to_minutes(2.99,219), time_to_minutes(3.39,219).` succeeds... Is that intentional?

Comment: No, but I needed something that converted double representation of 24h time to minutes. So by rounding up and down I managed to get it working. It is not designed to work backwards (meaning checking true/false).

Comment: I'd prefer using an unambiguous gap-less representation, with the floating point value `2.5` corresponding to "2 hours 30 minutes", and `2.9` to "2 hours 54 minutes"... However: YMMV!

Comment: There is `float_integer_part/1` and `float_fractional_part/1` exactly for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks, what what I needed.